# How to handle 25k .csv files and mapping to database?

Tags: mysql, csv, neo4j, database-administration

I have a situation that requires mapping over 25k unique csv files, into a MySQL database.

The problem is that each csv file will have unique column headings, and thus requires mapping the columns to correct tables/columns in the MySQL database.

So for example, we may find that column 2 in one csv file is the Country, but in another csv file it is column 6. Or we might find that Country just doesn't exist in a particular csv file. You can see why doing manual mapping of columns for 25k files is not practical.

The reason it needs mapping is because we want the ability to perform a search across all the files, based on a predefined structure.

For example, we will want to find travel companies in the UK that have more than 20 employees.

We need the ability to perform this query across all data in the files, to obtain the right results. The database structure has already been defined and have been parsing in csv files fine, until now we just realised there will be a huge number of csv files to do this mapping with.

Are we better off with a NoSQL solution? Would you recommend something like Neo4j? Is there a better solution for mapping unique csv files to structured MySQL schema?

Edit:
I am planning now for us to first parse the first row of every file, and store that in a new table associated to the file with a many-to-many relationship.
From this, will allow the user to define the matching table column to file column (since I suspect a large number of columns will be practically the same).
Then save this mapping data against the file and have an automated process then perform the insertion based on this mapping.

This should hopefully reduce the workload from having to set the mapping on each file individually, and instead focus on the mapping of associated columns across all files. It will still be a heavy task though I imagine.

Thanks

Comment: It is clear that the csv files are not in the same order, but they all have the same information? Same columns different order?

Comment: They have different data, not just columns ordered differently. There will be common columns such as email that the majority, if not all, will have. But yes this is the challenge - different data and different structure :)

Comment: Great. Given that you have a pre-defined MySQL schema:

(1) Do you want to keep rows that don't have all the info needed for the schema, or keep NULL values?

(2) Do you want to keep columns that have extra information that is not in the schema (is this a concern in your dataset?)

Comment: Thanks for helping btw. 
1) Yes - all the info required is optional, except the email column
2) No - don't need to keep information that is not part of the schema